# How to call webViewDidFinishLoad of my custom uiwebview class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I make a custom `UIWebView` class below.

`TestLib` derived from `UIWebView`.

I want to call `webViewDidFinishLoad` of my custom `UIWebView` class.

```
[TestLib.h]
@interface TestLib : UIWebView
{
}
@end

[TestLib.m]


[ViewController.h]
#import "TestLib.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIWebViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic)TestLib *myWebView;


[ViewContoroller.m]

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize myWebView

- (void) viewDidLoad {
   myWebView = [[TestLib alloc] init];
   [myWebView setDelegate: self];

   ...
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad: (UIWebView *)webView {
    // not call
}
```

Comment: where are you loading the content `webViewDidFinishLoad ` get called once content(HTML, text,...) loaded in webView.

Comment: @kmithi I wrote code simply. The 'init' method in TestLib load webpage like below.

self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"www.google.com"];
        
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [self loadRequest:request];
    }
    return self;

Comment: I think this webview does not know what is its delegate when it send a request in 'init' method

Comment: You need to set the delegate first then load the data, in your case you are loading data first and setting delegate latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you're attempting to create a UIWebView programmatically, then you shouldn't be calling the default initializer (use initWithFrame instead).
2. You need to move the load requests to the view controller's viewDidLoad method:

```c
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [myWebView setDelegate:self];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
    NSURLRequest *request =[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [myWebView loadRequest:request];
}
```

3. Add a semicolon to synthesize the property:

```c
@synthesize myWebView;
```

4. webViewDidFinishLoad method should look something like this:

```c
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

    // TestLib *customWebView = (TestLib *)webView; - type cast if needed
    NSLog(@"Webpage loaded OK");

}
```

If you are creating the UIWebView via Interface Builder, you'll want to omit the init method altogether and just connect your myWebView property as an IBOutlet:

```c
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet TestLib *myWebView;
```

Additionally, you'll want to change the custom class in Interface Builder from UIWebView to TestLib.